# How to regiser or add a control that nonautomatic validate in Angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular

After create a form by FormBuilder, I want to add a new control with some validators,but it auto validate and set errors in control.
I found it run `updateValueAndValidity` in FormControl constructor.

So how can i regiser or add a control after create a form that nonautomatic validate?

Some patch methods what I can think of but not so good:

- Set error null after add control: `this.form.controls['name'].setErrors({})`
- Set validators after add control: `this.form.controls['name'].setValidators(validators)`

Comment: Are you talking about built in  or self written  validators?  What is the concrete problem? An red error message without touching the control?

Comment: When register a new control, the error properties of the control are automatically displayed,  I prefer the error property on the control to have a value when I want it to check.

Comment: Please show me the htm code of mat-form-field, input and mat-error

Answer (score 0):

If you use an mat-error tag in a mat-form-field, then the error is only shown when the field is touched (and invalid):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    formControlName="name"
    matInput
    placeholder="User name"
  />
  <mat-error>
    Please enter a valid username
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

If the mat-error tag is outside of the mat-form-field, then you have to extend your *ngIf="..." at the mat-error tag.

After adding you can set the field as untouched:

```
 this.form.controls['name'].markAsUntouched({ onlySelf:true})
```